# Vector operation on pyspark dataframe

Tags: vector, pyspark

I'm new in pyspark.

My dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([[10,  8], [3,  5], [1,  3], [1,  5], [2,  8], [8,  7]], list('AB'))
df.show()

+---+---+
|  A|  B|
+---+---+
| 10|  8|
|  3|  5|
|  1|  3|
|  1|  5|
|  2|  8|
|  8|  7|
+---+---+
```

transfer col'A' & col'B' into vector by `VectorAssembler`:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler,Normalizer
Vector = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['A','B'], outputCol="Vector_AB").transform(df)
```

unit vector_AB by `Normalizer`:

```
Vector = Normalizer(inputCol="Vector_AB",outputCol="Unit_AB",p=2).transform(Vector)

+---+---+----------+--------------------+
|  A|  B| Vector_AB|             Unit_AB|
+---+---+----------+--------------------+
| 10|  8|[10.0,8.0]|[0.78086880944303...|
|  3|  5| [3.0,5.0]|[0.51449575542752...|
|  1|  3| [1.0,3.0]|[0.31622776601683...|
|  1|  5| [1.0,5.0]|[0.19611613513818...|
|  2|  8| [2.0,8.0]|[0.24253562503633...|
|  8|  7| [8.0,7.0]|[0.75257669470687...|
+---+---+----------+--------------------+
```

How to calculate the **inner product** of Vector_AB? (2 norm)

Like,
inputCol: `'Vector_AB'`-->`[10.0,8.0]`, get the outputCol: `Inner_Product_AB` -->(10^2+8^2) = `164`

I try to:

```
Vector = Vector.withColumn('Inner_Product_AB', Vector['A']*Vector['A']+Vector['B']*Vector['B'])
```

Is there any built-in function that can get this result?

My desired dataframe:

```
+---+---+----------+--------------------+----------------+
|  A|  B| Vector_AB|             Norm_AB|Inner_Product_AB|
+---+---+----------+--------------------+----------------+
| 10|  8|[10.0,8.0]|[0.78086880944303...|             164|
|  3|  5| [3.0,5.0]|[0.51449575542752...|              34|
|  1|  3| [1.0,3.0]|[0.31622776601683...|              10|
|  1|  5| [1.0,5.0]|[0.19611613513818...|              26|
|  2|  8| [2.0,8.0]|[0.24253562503633...|              68|
|  8|  7| [8.0,7.0]|[0.75257669470687...|             113|
+---+---+----------+--------------------+----------------+
```

Then I want to do vector operation: `col['Norm_AB']/col['Inner_Product_AB']`

Is there any built-in function that can do this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to calculate the inner product of Vector_AB? (2 norm)

One way is to define a UDF that operates on `pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector` object using built in function [`dot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector.html?highlight=dot#pyspark.ml.linalg.DenseVector.dot) i.e. inner product:

```
dot_prod_udf = F.udf(lambda v: int(v.dot(v)), LongType())
```

Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType


data = [
    {"A": 10, "B": 8},
    {"A": 3, "B": 5},
    {"A": 1, "B": 3},
    {"A": 1, "B": 5},
    {"A": 2, "B": 8},
    {"A": 8, "B": 7},
]

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

Vector = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["A", "B"], outputCol="Vector_AB").transform(df)

dot_prod_udf = F.udf(lambda v: float(v.dot(v)), FloatType())
norm_udf = F.udf(lambda x, y: x / y, VectorUDT())

Vector = Vector.withColumn("Inner_Product_AB", dot_prod_udf("Vector_AB"))
Vector = Vector.withColumn("Inner_Product_AB_sqrt", F.sqrt("Inner_Product_AB"))
Vector = Vector.withColumn("Norm_AB", norm_udf("Vector_AB", "Inner_Product_AB_sqrt"))
```

Result:

```
+---+---+----------+----------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
|A  |B  |Vector_AB |Inner_Product_AB|Inner_Product_AB_sqrt|Norm_AB                                 |
+---+---+----------+----------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
|10 |8  |[10.0,8.0]|164.0           |12.806248474865697   |[0.7808688094430304,0.6246950475544243] |
|3  |5  |[3.0,5.0] |34.0            |5.830951894845301    |[0.5144957554275265,0.8574929257125441] |
|1  |3  |[1.0,3.0] |10.0            |3.1622776601683795   |[0.31622776601683794,0.9486832980505138]|
|1  |5  |[1.0,5.0] |26.0            |5.0990195135927845   |[0.19611613513818404,0.9805806756909202]|
|2  |8  |[2.0,8.0] |68.0            |8.246211251235321    |[0.24253562503633297,0.9701425001453319]|
|8  |7  |[8.0,7.0] |113.0           |10.63014581273465    |[0.7525766947068778,0.658504607868518]  |
+---+---+----------+----------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How to do the operation `col['Vector_AB']/col['Inner_Product_AB']`?

Comment: @Drizzle Please see the updated answer. I included examples of calculating `dot` product, its `sqrt` and them `Norm_AB` by dividing the `DenseVector`.